# Update the working directory with part of a changeset

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I've created a changeset which contains a number of individual changes. I've realized that one of those changes might not have been a good idea, and I'd like to update my working directory to include only part of that changeset to work on, without throwing out the changeset itself.

In git terms, I want to do something similar to `git checkout -p HEAD~`, or the similar

```
git checkout -b newbranch
git reset HEAD~
git add -p
git checkout -- .
```

How can I do this in Mercurial?

Comment: Not everybody in hg-world can speak on and understand git-lingua, thus - git-wodoo is always useless for describing task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read *carefully* [`hg help revert`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/revert), pay special attention to `-r` option and NAME (ordinary list of [fileset](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/filesets)).

In your case (single changeset, part of which you want to eliminate from Working Dir), you have to:

- `hg up` to the *this* changeset
- `hg revert -r "p1(.)" set:SOME-FILESET` or, instead of fileset ("set:PATTERN" part), just "... FILE FILE2 FILE3 FILEN"

As result, you'll get in one readable command *modified Working Directory* with only needed part of changes in it

Comment: Ah, got it, thanks. I was looking at `hg up`, which basically plays the roll of `git checkout $REV`. `hg revert` is like `git checkout $REV -- $FILES`, and the `--interactive` option is attached only to `hg revert` and not `hg up`, for the same reasons that `--patch` can only be used the later form of `git checkout`.